# Getting Intersect Feature in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, intersection, features

I tried to get the intersect line feature if user placed point on that line.

I tried below:

```
class AddPoint(QgsMapToolEdit):
    def __init__(self, canvas, iface, Layer):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.iface = iface
        self.layer=layer
        QgsMapToolEdit.__init__(self, self.canvas)
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        click_point = event.snapPoint()
        geom = QgsGeometry().fromPointXY(click_point)
        feat=self.getLine(geom,self.layer)
        print(feat)
    def getLine(self,point,layer):
        bbx=point.boundingBox()
        for i in layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterRect(bbx)):
            if i.geometry().intersects(point):
                return i
        return None
```

But above code not returning any feature, why?

Comment: IMHO, without using snapping, it is almost not possible to get a point intersecting the line. One solution would be get the nearest line to the clicked point, but it may give the wrong line in areas with many lines.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to define a new method to get the intersected line. `QgsSnappingUtils` class has `snapToMap()` method which returns a `QgsPointLocator::Match` struct and it has `featureid()` method which returns the snapped feature id. Then, you can get the feature by id.

Use like this:

```
class AddPoint(QgsMapToolEdit):
    def __init__(self, canvas, iface, layer):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.iface = iface
        self.layer = layer
        QgsMapToolEdit.__init__(self, self.canvas)
        
        self.snapper = canvas.snappingUtils()
        config = QgsSnappingConfig()
        config.setEnabled(True)
        config.setType(QgsSnappingConfig.VertexAndSegment)
        config.setUnits(QgsTolerance.Pixels)
        config.setTolerance(12)
        config.setMode(2)
        self.snapper.setConfig(config)
        self.snapindicator = QgsSnapIndicator(canvas)
        
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        feat_id = self.snapper.snapToMap(event.pos()).featureId()
        print(f"Snapped feature id: {feat_id}")
        
        ### then you can get the feature ###
        feat = self.layer.getFeature(feat_id)
        
    def canvasMoveEvent(self, event):
        snapMatch = self.snapper.snapToMap(event.pos())
        self.snapindicator.setMatch(snapMatch)
        
        
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
t = AddPoint(canvas, iface, iface.activeLayer())
canvas.setMapTool(t)
```

[image]

Comment: It return the top feature id, if  Multiple Features avail in same Location is it return all ids?

Comment: I don't know, it returns snapped feature id in the active layer when I run it.

Comment: Could you share a sample data which produces the result you mentioned?